# How best execute query in background to not freeze application (.NET)

Tags: sql, multithreading, .net-4.0

My WinForm apps needs to execute complex query with significant execution time, I have no influence (about 10mins)
When query is executing user sees 'application not responding' in task manager, which is really confusing to user, also not very professional...

I believe that query shall be executed in different thread or so.  Have tried some approaches but have difficulties to make it really working (execute query, force main application wait result, return back to main app, possibility to cancel execution etc)

I wonder if you have own / good working solution for that. **Code samples would be also very welcome** :)

Also I believe there might exist some ready to use utilities / frameworks allowing simple execution of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ExecuteQuery` if the method you want to execute, you can do:

```
void SomeMethod() {
    var thread = new Thread(ExecuteQuery);
    thread.Start();
}

void ExecuteQuery() {
    //Build your query here and execute it.
}
```

If `ExecuteQuery` receives some parameters, like:

```
void ExecuteQuery(string query) {
    //...
}
```

You can do:

```
var threadStarter = () => { ExecuteQuery("SELECT * FROM [Table]"); };
var thread = new Thread(ThreadStarter);
thread.Start();
```

If you want to stop the execution of the background thread, avoid calling `thread.Abort()` method. That will `kill` the thread, and you do not want this, because some incosistency could appear in your database.

Instead, you can have a `bool` variable visible from `ExecuteQuery` and from outside you can set it to `True` when you want to stop it. Then all you have to do is check in some parts of the code inside `ExecuteQuery` if that variable is still `True`. Otherwise, do some *rollback* to maintain the database stable.

Be sure you set that `bool` variable [`volatile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7%28VS.71%29.aspx)

**Edit:**
If you want the UI *to wait* from the background thread, I usually do:

- Start the background thread
- Start some progress bar in the UI
- *Disable* some controls (like buttons, etc) to avoid the user to click them while the background thread is working (eg: If you're executing the thread when a user clicks a button, then you should disable that button, otherwise multiple queries will be ocurring at the same time).

After finished the thread, you can stop progress bar and enable controls again.

How to know when the thread finished? You can use Events for that. Just create an event and fire it when it finishes, and do whatever you want inside the event handler...

**Be sure** you're accessing correctly to UI controls from the background thread, otherwise it will give you an error.

Comment: Looks good and simple. Will try it! But are you sure that in this solution UI will 'wait' until thread completes ? Or some additional check needs to be added ?

Comment: @Maciej After the line `thread.Start()` the method will maintain the execution, and at the same time, `ExecuteQuery` will start its execution.

Comment: I know. But what need to be done in main app (UI). Shall I display eg modal form saying eg "please wait query is executing" then after thread completes return to app and close this form and back to app?

Comment: @Maciej Of course. You could do that (usually done by lots of applications). I edited my answer and added another way of doing this.

Comment: @Oscar- I like your answer it was very informative and documented by samples. Will go that way - many thanks !

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach here would be to do that work from a BackgroundWorker. [MSDN has examples for this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). This then executes on a worker thread, with events for completion/error/etc. It can also support cancel, but your operation needs to be coded to be interruptable.

Another approach is the Task API in 4.0; but if you use this you'll need to get back to the UI thread (afterwards) yourself. With BackgroundWorker this is automatic (the events are raised on the UI thread).

Comment: For *winforms*, probably BackgroundWorker is more convenient as the hooks to get back the the UI thread are already there.

Comment: I dont know why but I dont like BackgroundWorker, I feel like I'm not really controlling that (you know kind of black box..).

Comment: @Maciej - then use any approach you choose ;p There are many - just remember to use `Control.Invoke` to get back to the UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to threads and task is simple (as it seems), you should try to use [standard background worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) component.