# Connecting to SQL Server without freezing WPF

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var sampleMessageDialog = new SampleMessageDialog
            {
                Message = { Text = "Failed to connect" }
            };

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionS"].ConnectionString);

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        //  await DialogHost.Show(sampleMessageDialog, "RootDialog");
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await DialogHost.Show(sampleMessageDialog, "RootDialog");
    }
}
```

Everything seem to run smoothly when the credentials are correct. However, when I enter the wrong credentials for the SQL Server connection string, it seem to freeze the second I click the button and the dialog only show after freezing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How best execute query in background to not freeze application (.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919964/how-best-execute-query-in-background-to-not-freeze-application-net)

Comment: appears thread blocks longer when you try opening connection while providing wrong credentials. try using `await con.OpenAsync();` instaed.

Comment: Your user is going to enter credentials for a database connection?  Not usually a good idea. I would suggest making the connection timeout longer rather than shorter would improve security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears thread blocks longer when you try opening connection while providing wrong credentials. try using `await con.OpenAsync();` instead to free up UI thread.

Comment: That seem to work but unless I change timeout, It's taking too long to show the Dialog (but yes, not freezing). Is it possible to show my circular progressbar for example until the Dialog/reply from database is returned?

Comment: async will help you to not block UI thread but as per your code, dialog will appear only once connection is opened..is that what you intend ?

Comment: The UI is no longer freezing. However, If the connection timeout is set to 30 for example, nothing will happen to the UI. Instead, the user will wait 30 seconds until the Dialog appear and tell him that the connection is not succesfull. So what I'm asking is, If there is something I could do about that? Like show a progressBar between the time I click the button and the return of failed connection occurs?

Comment: cool. How to implement progress bar, I would suggest you to look at another SO post :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447856/displaying-a-progressbar-while-executing-an-sql-query

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look. Now and you mentioned, If you don't mind, what is the difference between BackGroundWorker/delegate invoke and Async that I just did? don't they serve for the same purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to connect async but you can set the connection timeout.

[SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout(v=vs.110).aspx)

Not seeing the purpose of the await on the DialogHost.Show.

Comment: The connection timeout only affects the connection or queries too? also, If for example, I set it to 1 second, is it sufficent to make a successful connection? or in other words, does a connection with correct credentials takes less then 1 second?

Comment: Documentation is pretty clear to me.  I cannot speak for your environment.